# Jms connection timeout

Tags: connection, jms, azureservicebus, connection-timeout

I'm using jms to publish messages to Azure service bus and jmsListener to fetch published data from service bus.
Sometimes I come across below error:

Caused by: org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.exceptions.ProviderConnectionRemotelyClosedException: The connection was inactive for more than the allowed 300000 milliseconds and is closed by container 'LinkTracker'. jakarta.jms.JMSException: Transport closed due to the peer exceeding our requested idle-timeout

I tried setting idle timeout in properties file. But that is also for that duration, I don't want it to go into timeout, connection should be there always. Anyway to configure it?

Also I heard about maxidleTime property for that -1 value disables timeout.
Can someone guide on this

Comment: try using ```ConnectionFactory factory = new ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory();
factory.setMaxIdleTime(-1);```